# Can I update child table without updating parent table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

see table for example

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id serial not null,
  CONSTRAINT parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  id serial not null,
  parent_id serial not null,
  username` varchar(90) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT child_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT parent_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES parent (id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

is there anyway i can update the username in child table? if yes how can i update it with php code.

if no what is the other option?

Comment: You can run an `update` query on child table, like any other php query and update the values.

Comment: Please be more specific about the kind of database you are using (mysql/oracle/...)

Comment: @Blablaenzo im not sure but im just using phpmyadmin

Comment: What commands do you use in php to work with database? Or you never work with db?

Comment: @fusion3k $parent_id = $_POST['parent_id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql = "UPDATE child SET username = '$username' WHERE parent_id = $parent_id";

Comment: **Please** retrieve your database kind

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `child` SET `username` = '$username' WHERE id = '$id'
```

replace `$username` and `$id` with your desired values.

Comment: in phpmyadmin it work but in php code it doesnt update

Comment: You **have to know** the db kind. Otherwise it is impossible to work with it. You can find it on phpMyAdmin homepage (see this [pic](http://i.imgur.com/vZrqpcu.png) as example)

Comment: Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.8-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: MariaDB is 99% MySQL compatible. You have to start with a php/MySQL tutorial (start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) and follow instructions for PDO driver). Without a tutorial, you'll lose a lot of time. Really a lot of time.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask again if something is unclear